Can I Reuse a Google Account for a New Play Store Developer Account After Closure?
I've recently encountered an issue where my Google Play Developer account was closed due to inactivity. Google's policy notifications were sent to the account owner's email and account admins, but unfortunately, I missed these warnings, leading to the account closure. According to the closure notification, the developer account registration fee is non-refundable, and the suggestion was to create a new account for publishing apps on Google Play.
Here's where I need some guidance:
Reusing Google Account for New Developer Account: Is it possible to use the same Google account (email) to create a new Play Store developer account? After the closure, when I attempt to access the Play Store developer console with my original account, all controls and menus appear grayed out and disabled, with only the closure message displayed.
Any insights or advice on how to navigate this situation would be greatly appreciated. I'm particularly interested in understanding the best practices for setting up a new account while dealing with the restrictions imposed by the closure of my previous account.
Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions!

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Unfortunately, after your Google Play Developer account is closed for inactivity you can't use it anymore or at least with the same Google Account.
According to Closure of inactive developer accounts, it states that your account will be permanently closed if you do not take the steps to keep your developer account after you have been notified that your account is marked to be closed for inactivity.

What will happen when my developer account becomes inactive?
...
The email will indicate the steps that you can take to keep your developer account and the date by which these steps should be completed. Failure to follow these steps will result in the permanent closure of your developer account, and the registration fee will not be refunded.

Additionally, the Enforcement Process Policy denotes that when your dormant account, an account that is inactive or abandoned, is closed, you will not be able to reactivate it.

Dormant Accounts
...
Closure of a dormant account will not limit your ability to create a new account in the future if you decide to publish on Google Play. You will not be able to reactivate your account and any previous apps or data will not be available on a new account.

So it seems like you are not able to reactivate your Google Play Developer account using the same Google Account after it is closed for inactivity/abandonment.
